# Direct Proof: For all n(n is a natural number) 5 divides n^5 - n

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In order for $n^5 - n$ divisible by $5$, $n^5 - n = 5 x + 0$ (for some $x$, $x$ is a natural number)
I simplified the $(n^5 - n) = n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$ and I do not know what to do next.

And I tried something else like $(n^5 - n) = n (n^4 - 1)$, but now I need to show $(n^4 - 1)$ is divisible by $5$, how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This is [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) with $p=5$

Comment: You could prove this by induction, since $(n+1)^5-(n+1)=5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+(n^5-n)$

Comment: It should be possible to write $\frac{n^5 - n}{5} = c_5 \binom{n}{5} + c_4 \binom{n}{4} + \cdots + c_1 \binom{n}{1} + c_0$ for some integers $c_5 = 24, c_4, \ldots, c_0$.

Comment: "but now I need to show (n4−1) is divisible by 5, how do I do that? "  Well you only have to show it for when $n$ is not divisible $5$.  (If $5|n$ then you are done).  Are you familiar with Fermat's Little Theorem.  If not consider that $n=5k+1$ means $5|n-1$. and $n=5k-1$ means $5|n+1$. Remains to show if $n=5k \pm 2$ then $n^2=25k^2-10k +4$ and so $5|n^2 + 1$.  That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $n\equiv 0,\pm 1,\pm 2\pmod 5$.

If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ then $5|n$ and $5|n(n^2 + 1)(n+1)(n-1)$.

If $n \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$ then $5|n\mp 1$ and $5|n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$.

And if $n \equiv \pm 2$ then $n^2 \equiv 4 \equiv -1$ and $5|n^2+1$ and $5|n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$.

..... alternative let $n = 5k + i; i = 0,1,2,3,4$

$(5k+i)((5k+i)^2 + 1)(5k + i + 1)(5k + i - 1)\equiv $

$i(i^2 + 1)(i+1)(i-1)\equiv $

$i(i^2 + 1)(i^2-1)\equiv $

$i(i^4 - 1) \equiv $

$i^5 - i\pmod 5$.

It's now a matter of showing $i^5 \equiv i \pmod 5$ for $i = 0,1,2,3,4$.

If you know Fermat's Little Theorem you are done.  FLT says *precisely* that.

If you don't,  there are only $5$ cases to test:

$0^5\equiv 0; 1^5 \equiv 1; 2^5\equiv 32 \equiv 2; 3^5 \equiv 3^4\cdot 3\equiv 81\cdot 3\equiv 3;  4^5 \equiv 4^2\cdot 4^2\cdot 4 \equiv 16\cdot 16\cdot 4\equiv 1\cdot 1\cdot 4 \equiv 4$.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the factorization modulo 5, we can factor that quadratic term as:

$$x^2+1 \equiv (x-2)(x-3) \mod 5$$

That means your factorization can be written as:

$$n^5 - n \equiv n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4) \mod 5$$

Since every residue class is a root, no matter what $n$ we pick, we will always get a number that is $0 \mod 5$.